# HttpFileCollectionBase не содержит реализации Add

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть веб-сервис, для передачи файлов на этот веб-сервис решил использовать `HttpFileCollectionBase`, добавил метод в котором в качестве одного из параметров используется `HttpFileCollectionBase`, но при компиляции получаю следующую ошибку

> Чтобы поддерживать сериализацию XML, типы, которые наследуют от
>   ICollection, должны иметь реализацию
>   Add(System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase) на всех уровнях иерархии
>   наследования. System.Web.HttpFileCollectionBase не содержит реализации
>   Add(System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase).

Не совсем понятно почему не реализован этот метод и каким образом нужно реализовать добавление.

update: В первом проекте есть service referense на веб-сервис второго проекта и вызывается метод `IncomingRequestCreate`, для того чтобы передать файлы между проектами.

```
public class RequestCreate
{
    ...
    public HttpFileCollectionBase attachFiles { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public ResponseResult IncomingRequestCreate(RequestCreate request)
{
    //work with file
}
```

При попытке скомпилировать второй проект возникает описываемая ошибка.

Comment: покажите свой код

Comment: @Bulson обновил

Comment: Вот [урок](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318425/how-to-send-and-receive-binary-documents-by-using-an-asp-net-web-servi) по передаче и приему файлов, в котором прекрасно все работает через привычный `FileStream`, но вы, похоже, не ищете простых путей.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ банальный, но все же: не используйте `HttpFileCollectionBase` для передачи списка файлов - этот класс не является XML-сериализуемым.

Создайте свой тип данных для представления файла, и передавайте обычный массив или список таких объектов.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду массив 'HttpPostedFileBase' ?

Comment: @e1s нет, этот тип данных тоже не подготовлен для нормальной XML-сериализации. Создайте новый класс для представления загруженного файла.

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить на примере что за структуру вы имеете ввиду? Спасибо. На ум приходит только массив 'byte'

Comment: @e1s а имя файла вы где хранить будете? :-) Или гуид какой-нибудь? Я-то откуда знаю что вам от файла надо?

Comment: мне надо сохранить их на hdd и проблема в том что они могут быть довольно объемными

Comment: @e1s какое отношение объем файлов имеет к вопросу?